# Java tree beginner questions?

Tags: java

Today i was told to create tree data structure with the below class,

```
public class Node(){
private string lable;
private List<Node> children;
}
```

After started to create the tree, i struck at very first.

It contains Node inside a node. I am totally confused. Well, tree maybe very familiar to you. 
You may think `Whats this! Its clear. How you getting confused` something like that.

For me, this the first time i am trying to create a tree in java. To be honest, i only used setters and getters inside a class in java. With these methods, I cannot think of inserting new nodes after the first level.

I have seen some examples in google and many in stackoverflow. But for a beginner(in tree) like me they looks incomplete. May be they may thought, the OP can continue with that.

If anyone explain me its concept and how to add more children, with any generic example i would be appreciative.

**Update:**

It may look weired to you, but this is how i started at the beginning.

```
Node node = new Node();
String label = "Bikes";
ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();

    Node childNode = new Node();
    childNode.setLabel("Yamaha");
    children.add(childNode);

    childNode = new Node();
    childNode.setLabel("Suzuki");
    children.add(childNode);

    childNode = new Node();
    childNode.setLabel("Honda");
    children.add(childNode);

    node.setLabel(label);
    node.setChildren(children);
```

After that, like i told i cannot think for next level.
After doing some searches i have found that they are having a method `addChild()`

Then i created mine,

```
    public void addChildren(Node node){
    children.add(node);
}
```

I continued like this,

```
        ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();

    node.setLabel(label);
    node.addChildren(node);
```

Now again i strucked here. Again i cannot think of adding more branches to the root node. i hope this makes some what clear.

Comment: Have you bothered to Google for some examples?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question...

Comment: Are familiar with the `List` interface?

Comment: @DVK `I have seen some examples in google and many in stackoverflow. But for a beginner(in tree) like me they looks incomplete...`

Comment: @Jhurtado  - then he should have posted specific example that he doesn't get and asked what was unclear about it.

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler: yes, i am familiar with it.

Comment: @DVK: I will update now. Thanks.

Comment: @Jesus Ramos: While searching for examples in stackoverflow, somewhere else i saw one comment similar to `Sounds like a homework question... `. I have been developing an web app for past 6 months. I am the low experienced guy in my team of 3 peoples. why dont a 25 year old working professional may not came across any use cases that needs knowledge about tree?

Comment: @TamilVendhan : Just sounded like a homework question, I've asked students many times to implement their own tree's or linked lists and this looks exactly like the format I present it to them. I apologize but this seems like a very standard topic that most developers know.

Comment: @Jesus Ramos: Of-course. It may be  because of i am new. Everyone starts from school right :) . I need move fast on learning these things. I just thought i could learn all these when it comes with a use case. But i admit that i worths if i learn them before i encounters any use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First drop the () in the class name:

Should be:

```
public class Node { 
....
```

**edit**

<sub>*I press sumbit before time. Here's the complete answer ( hint: you can undo the downvote now :P )*</sub>

They are called trees , because one branch may either have leafs or other branches.

That's why a node may have other nodes inside.

When a node doesn't have children, then in a leaf. When it does is a branch.

So, it would be something like this:

```
import java.util.*;
// This is your existing code:
class Node { 
    private String label;
    private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();

    // Here's how you would build one with that strucure
    public static void main( String ... args ) { 

        Node one = new Node();
        one.label = "1";

        Node two = new Node();
        two.label = "2";

        Node root = new Node();
        root.label = "plus";
        root.children.add( one );
        root.children.add( two );

        print( root );
    }

    // Here's how you'll print the values
    static void print( Node node ) { 

         System.out.println( node.label );

         for( Node child : node.children ) { 
            // if child is a branch 
            if( child.children.size() > 0 ) { 
                // print the branch ( recursively ) 
                print( child );
             } else { 
                // is a leaf, just print the label.
                System.out.println( "-- ["+child.label+"]" );
             }
          }
     }
}
```

That is a root node ( "plus" ) has two childs ( "1" and "2" ) those nodes in turn may have other nodes ( that's not the case here ) like a tree does.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Let me know if this is clear enough as for ( levels ) goes. You can also try to model an organization chart ( as deep as: ) `General -> Colonel -> Captain -> Sargeant -> Private`

Answer (score 2):

Its all about composite pattern :
[wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).
Try to understand it first.I think the Java syntax is not a problem.
I hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your original question is fairly vague but to answer your ? of node inside on node. If you visualize it, A tree consists of branches(nodes), and each branch can have child branches, and so on.

Good explanation [here](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html).

Answer (score 1):

The tree starts with a parent node. Each node has a label and can have 0 to many children. The reason you have a list of nodes is because those are the child nodes of that given node.

Answer (score 1):

I think the bigger issue here is the way you are thinking about how to write a function to solve a task on a tree. For lists, it is straight forward. You loop over the items of the list and perform some action using the current item of the list.

However, since trees are a different data structure, you need a different method to perform similar steps. The easiest way to work with a tree is to write a [recursive method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Recursion_in_computer_science). This is a method that at some point calls itself in order to do more work.

```
recursiveFunction(Node n) {
  do work for current node

  for(Node child : children) {
    recursiveFunction(child);
  }
}
```

It may take a little thinking to see what work needs to be done on the current node and if there are some special cases based on it's values, but the structure will look similar.

Answer (score 0):

In OscarRYZ's answer In the recursive method `print(Node)`, the `print(Node)` method is called in itself:
`if( child.children.size() > 0 ) {`
 
                `// print the branch ( recursively )`
 
                `print( child );`
             `}else {`
 
                `// is a leaf, just print the label.`
                `System.out.println( "-- ["+child.label+"]" );`
             `}`

this `print(Node)` method will be called recursively as long as the node is a branch, and when it gets to a leaf, it will just print the leaf's label with 
`System.out.println( "-- ["+child.label+"]" );`
 and go back to its branch.